# Get Position of listview from Checkbox in the Adapter with Custom Listview Layout

Tags: listview, position, android-adapter, android-checkbox, android-viewholder

I am trying to get the listview position from the checkbox on the listview. This has to be done in the Custom List view adapter.
This is the code I currently have which includse a Checkbox on check listener for to get the position of the ListView unfortunatly it is not working and I am unable to get the position from the oncheck listener.

Here is the Adapter:

```
public class AdapterOrderProgress extends ArrayAdapter<DataSetTasks>{

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView TaskName;
    CheckBox TaskStart;
    CheckBox TaskEnd;
}


public AdapterOrderProgress(Context context, ArrayList<DataSetTasks> tasks) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_layout_orderprogress, tasks);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    DataSetTasks tasks = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout_orderprogress, parent, false);

        viewHolder.TaskName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTaskName);
        viewHolder.TaskStart = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbxStartTask);
        viewHolder.TaskEnd = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbxEndTask);

        viewHolder.TaskStart.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.TaskStart.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    viewHolder.TaskName.setText(tasks.TaskName);
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}

CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        int position = buttonView.getTag();
    }
};
}
```

Here is the XML for the custom List view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/cbxStartTask" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Task Here"
                android:id="@+id/txtTaskName"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/cbxEndTask"/>
```

And the Main Activity:

```
public void PopulateOrderProgressList(){

    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();

    ArrayList<DataSetTasks> arrayofTasks = new ArrayList<>();

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    AdapterOrderProgress adapter = new AdapterOrderProgress(getContext(), arrayofTasks);
    // Attach the adapter to a ListView

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    try {

        String sql = "exec sp_Get_Production_Tasks\n@Production_ID  = " + ProductionID + ",@Product_ID  = " + ProductID;

        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String TaskName = rs.getString("Task_Name").trim();

            DataSetTasks newTask = new DataSetTasks(TaskName);

            adapter.add(newTask);
        }

    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your **AdapterOrderProgress** class as:

```
public class AdapterOrderProgress extends ArrayAdapter<DataSetTasks> {

Context _context;

List<DataSetTasks> _listTasks = new ArrayList<DataSetTasks>();

ViewHolder viewHolder;

public AdapterOrderProgress(Context context, ArrayList<DataSetTasks> tasks) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_layout_orderprogress, tasks);

    this._context = context;
    this._listTasks = tasks;
}

@Override
public Contact getItem(int position) {
    return _listTasks.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return _listTasks.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return pos;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Get the data item for this position
    DataSetTasks tasks = _listTasks(position);

    View view = convertView;

    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if(view == null) 
    {
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout_orderprogress, null);
    } 
    else 
    {
        view = convertView;
    }

    // View Holder
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    viewHolder.TaskName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTaskName);
    viewHolder.TaskStart = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbxStartTask);
    viewHolder.TaskEnd = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbxEndTask);

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    viewHolder.TaskName.setText(tasks.TaskName);

    // CheckBox click listener
    viewHolder.TaskStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;

            if (checkBox.isChecked()) 
            {
                ................
            } 
            else 
            {
                ................
            }
        }
    });

    view.setTag(tasks);

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return view;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView TaskName;
    CheckBox TaskStart;
    CheckBox TaskEnd;
}
}
```